# function not printing correctly in c

Tags: c, arrays, maze, ansi-c

I am trying to build a dynamic maze i got to the part where i get the size and get the chars that i need to build the maze from them.
but the function thats build the maze prints it really asymmetrical how can i fix that?

my code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

 char **board;
 int size = 0;

 void print_Board();
 void initialize_Board();

int main()
{
  initialize_Board();
  print_Board();

 return 0;
}

/*initialize the board*/
void initialize_Board()
 {
    int i, j;//indexs
    char s;
    scanf("%d", &size);

 board = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)* (size)); 
 if (!board) { printf("ERROR - memroy allocation.\n"); exit(1); }

 for (i = 0; i < size; i++)//for loops to build the board for the game
 {
    board[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(size));                              
   if (!board[i]) { printf("ERROR - memroy allocation, for loop\n");  
      exit(1); 
    }

    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &s);
        board[i][j] = s;
    }//for col

    printf("\n");

  }//for row
}

//print the board
void print_Board()
  {
    int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
        printf("%c ", board[i][j]); //print the value in the [i][j] place.
        }//for col

        printf("\n");

       }//for row
 }
```

Comment: Mind posting a sample output?

Comment: Ever considered posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: One guess is that you press Enter after each row, and that is read as an extra character by `scanf`.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &s);` --> `scanf(" %c", &s);`

Comment: BLUEPIXY thanks! fix it!

Comment: You should really consider not using globals for `board` and `size`. Simply declare them in `main` and pass them as parameters to `initialize_Board` and `print_Board`. There are times when globals are required -- this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
{
    scanf("%c", &s);
    board[i][j] = s;
}//for col
```

To:

```
for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    scanf("%c ", &s);
    board[i][j] = s;
}//for col
board[i][j] = '\n'; // Add new line to end of row making it a string.
```

This ensures that each character is read and the return char is discarded.

and change:

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        printf("%c ", board[i][j]); //print the value in the [i][j] place.
    }//for col

    printf("\n");

}//for row
```

to:

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%s", board[i]); //print the values in the [i] row.
}
```

This prints each row with a newline at the end.